# Dynamically add HTML to ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, declarative

Could someone please advise what the "correct" method is for adding HTML content to an ASP.NET page dynamically?

I am aware of the following declarative method.

```
//Declaration
<%= MyMethodCall() %>


//And in the code behind.
protected String MyMethodCall()
{
    return "Test Value";
}
```

Is there a better or best practice way?

**EDIT: I am building a Galleriffic photo gallery dynamically depending on the images located in a specific folder.**

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Depends what you want to do.

For controls/text I normally use a `LiteralControl` and set the `Text` property as the HTML I want to add, then this control can be added anywhere on the page that you want it to appear

LiteralControl reference is
[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.literalcontrol.aspx)

ok seeing as you want it for Galleriffic, I guess it would pseudo-appear as such...

```
 LiteralControl imageGallery = new LiteralControl();
    string divStart = @"<div id='thumbs'><ul class='thumbs noscript'>";
    imageGallery.Text += divStart;
    foreach ([image in images])
    {
      string imageHTML = @"<li><a class='thumb' name='optionalCustomIdentifier' ref='path/to/slide' title='your image title'>
                           <img src='path/to/thumbnail' alt='your image title again for graceful degradation' /></a>
                           <div class='caption'>[caption]<div></li>";

      imageGallery.Text += imageHTML;
    }
    string divEnd = @"</ul></div>";
    imageGallery.Text += divEnd;

    this.[divOnPage].Controls.Add(imageGallery);
```

Comment: What are the advantages of this approach as opposed to the method I specified? PS: Thank you for the comprehensive example!

Comment: This code is awfull. Why not use a repeater? or a for in the .aspx. Concatenating strings to create HTML is not my idea of a best practice

Comment: Assembling markup in C# code should be the absolute last resort as it creates a maintenance nightmare that would make Cthulhu proud. At the very least, encapsulate into a user or server control.

Comment: yes, you're right in terms of the string/HTML concat, I just quickly put that example together to illustrate the point

Answer (score 12):

Aspx :

```
<div id="DIV1" runat="server"></div>
```

Code behind :

```
DIV1.InnerHtml = "some text";
```

Comment: For anything substantially, like a "photo gallery", I'd recommend to use something like react, but this question is from 2011, and for something quick and dirty, this answer is an excellent solution

Answer (score 6):

There are several ways to do that, which to use really depends on your scenario and preference.

- Web User Controls: Can be added dynamically and you get the full editor support of Visual Studio.
- XML literals (VB.NET only): Very convenient way to quickly put together HTML in code.
- Templates: Add a plain HTML document to your solution and include it as a resource. Then you'll get editor support and you won't clutter your code with HTML source.

Answer (score 0):

Another option

```
//.aspx
<asp:Literal ID="myText" runat="server"></asp:Literal>


//.aspx.cs
protected Literal myText;
myText.Text = "Hello, World!";
```