# Generate HTML script through Programming in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

***i wants to generate an chart like given in image in html dynamically from code behind in asp.net.***

[image]

their would be an unique serial number at the top left of each block which would be unique & total 1000 in 10 charts.

thats why hardcoding 1000 blocks would be much difficult although i have tried.

```
<DIV STYLE="position:absolute; top:9px; left:12px; width:200px; height:25px">
<IMG SRC="bricks.png" width="250px" height="45" >
<DIV STYLE="position:absolute; top:0px; left:5px; width:200px; height:25px">
<FONT SIZE="+0" COLOR="00ff00">0001</FONT>
</DIV>
</DIV>


<DIV STYLE="position:absolute; top:9px; left:270px; width:200px; height:25px">
<IMG SRC="bricks.png" height="45" width="150px">
<DIV STYLE="position:absolute; top:0px; left:5px; width:200px; height:25px">
<FONT SIZE="+0" COLOR="00ff00">0002</FONT>
</DIV>
</DIV>
<br>


<DIV STYLE="position:absolute; top:9px; left:12px; width:200px; height:75px">
<IMG SRC="bricks.png" height="45" width="150px">
<DIV STYLE="position:absolute; top:50px; left:5px; width:200px; height:25px">
<FONT SIZE="+0" COLOR="00ff00">0003</FONT>
</DIV>
</DIV>
```

and also:

```
 <IMG SRC="bricks.png" height="45" width="150px">
 <DIV STYLE="position:absolute; top:9px; left:270px; width:200px; height:25px">
    <FONT SIZE="+0" COLOR="00ff00">0002</FONT>
 </DIV>
```

Comment: What is the purpose? Do you want to generate this type of HTML dynamically on client side? Or it is for one time development purpose?

Comment: i have 10 tabs each tab would have 1 chart where sold blocks would be highlighted based on given year.
means charts in 10 tabs would be generated on first time at page initialization & after that when ever year value would be change in combobox.

Answer (score 3):

If you are much familiar with HTML there are much options in front of you.

ASPX Page

```
<form id="demo" runat="server">
<%=DrawHtml() %>

</form>
```

.CS Page

```
public string DrawHtml()
{
string Content="";
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
Content+="Hello</br>";
}
return Content;
}
```

Alternatively If you are Following Dynamic Html rendering using placeholder,
use `HtmlGenericControl` Class instead.

You will get better tutorial from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25573/Building-ASP-NET-Web-Pages-Dynamically-in-the-Code) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508666/dynamically-add-html-to-asp-net-page)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest going through some tutorials on [www.asp.net](http://www.asp.net) to get familiar with asp and ow html is rendered to the page.

Here is a basic example that uses a foreach loop, which you can use to render your page when you have to repeat html rendering.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You really take a look at the Literal control, this can be used to write out an HTML. The Literal control will get substituted at run time.
[Asp Literal](http://www.dotnetperls.com/aspliteral)
Found this also on MSDN [Literal Controls Explained](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.text.aspx)