# Display text report on aspx page with out using repeater control

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to write text report on aspx page from the table by using c#.The report should like below and i don't want to sue repeater for this because i have multiple value with same name that way i don't want display them again and again on the page.

```
    parent: something
       categoey: something
           value: something

parent: something
       categoey: something
           value: something

parent: something
       categoey: something
           value: something
```

Any Help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply generate the HTML to show the content and add it to a literal control.

Place a `Literal Control` in your WebPage.

```
string Content="";
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
Content +="Dynamic Content<br/>";
}
ltrlControl.Text=Content;
```

There are number of alternatives in asp.net to generate dynamic HTML.
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508666/dynamically-add-html-to-asp-net-page)

For your Example,

```
string Content="";
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
    Content +="parent: something<br/>";
    Content +="categoey: something<br/>";
    Content +="value: something<br/><br/><br/>";
    }
    ltrlControl.Text=Content;
```

I hope you are much familiar with HTML.

Comment: Literal control display only one value but i want to repeat it.

Comment: You are asking How to generate HTML dynamically and the answer says about it.